# Find string in a List of Tuples

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, compare, tuples

I am appending a tuple to the list if I don't find the string.

```
if list2[0] in hr:
    print "X"
else:
    hr.append((list2[0], 1))
```

`print "X"` is arbitary.
But the code section is not going into the `if` block.

Also
I want to increment the value of the second item of the tuple of the list `hr`
Please provide suggestions.

Edit:

`list2` is a list of the form `['09', '14', '16']`

And `hr` is the list of tuples as can be seen from the code
`hr.append((list2[0], 1))`

`hr` is of the form `[('09', 1), ('18', 1)]`

Also the increment is to change `[('09', 1), ('18', 1)]` to `[('09', 1), ('18', 2)]` when encounter `'18'` again in `list2`
All the operations are being carried out inside a loop reading a file.

Comment: what is list2 and h2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
item_found = False
for index, item in enumerate(hr):
    if list2[0] == item[0]:
        item_found = True #found the item
        hr[index] = (item[0], item[1]+1) #increment by 1
        break #don't loop more than we need to
if not item_found:
    hr.append((list2[0], 1)) #add new item
```